# Journals that publish theoretical analyses of existing algorithms

Tags: computational-physics, publications

In computational physics, the vast majority of papers has the following structure

- They propose some new algorithm, or improvement to an existing one
- They give numerical examples, ideally comparing relevant characteristics of their new method with existing methods

I am wondering which journals would publish a theoretical analysis of an existing algorithm, e.g. "Algorithm X was previously hypothesized to have stability condition Y (but this was not proven), and this is indeed true because (math proof)".

Such a paper would deviate from the structure above in that it neither proposes a new algorithm, nor provides numerical examples. It "merely" proves that an existing algorithm has certain characteristics.

Comment: This sounds like something that could also be published in an applied maths journal.

Comment: Not enough points to comment. However, if the condition is relevant, you can submit it to most appl. maths journals and there are many examples of such articles. The specific journal depends very much on the algorithm.

Comment: Just publish it where the original algorithm was introduced and/or is referenced.